# RAND not different for every row in T-SQL UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the follow T-SQL to update a table with test data:

```
UPDATE
SomeTable
SET
    Created = GETDATE ( ) - CAST ( RAND ( ) * 365 AS int ) ,
    LastUpdated = GETDATE ( ) - CAST ( RAND ( ) * 365 AS int )
```

I want it to pick random daes in the past year, unfortunately it uses the same date for every row.  what is the best way to get it to be random every row it updates?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))`

- NEWID returns a GUID
- CHECKSUM makes it int, randomly
- The int seeds the RAND

In your case, you could modulo the checkum because CHECKSUM(NEWID()) is already random.

```
CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 365
```

Comment: Great stuff.  I wonder why they made it not vary per row, but that question is for another day :)

Comment: AS an aside, your method does have one issue: it brings back negative values.  Easy fix though: ABS( CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 365 )

Comment: Great solution. And just shift and multiply by whatever you want to get an int within a range.

Answer (score 3):

if you only want days from the past year use this (based on @gbn's answer):

```
select GETDATE ( ) - ABS( CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 365 )
```