# Different rand() value for multiple rows SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, random

When I use this query, it assigns every row to the same value.
Is there anyway to make this not happen?

```
UPDATE Team
SET GroupID = CAST(RAND() * 4 AS INT)
```

TO CLARIFY:
This is to be used with Netbeans to assign group numbers to teams.

```
+----+----------+-------------+------------------+---------+
| ID |  School  | TeamCaptain |      Email       | GroupID |
+----+----------+-------------+------------------+---------+
|  1 | School 1 | John        | email@email.com  | NULL    |
|  2 | School 2 | James       | email2@email.com | NULL    |
+----+----------+-------------+------------------+---------+
```

SandySands method works. However, is there any way to make it so that the same number can't appear more than 4 times?

Comment: use a WHERE condition for filtration @Christopher

Comment: I think you can make you SQL field just auto increment and everything will work

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214748/rand-not-different-for-every-row-in-t-sql-update

Comment: Provide table structure and you expected output in the form of tables @Christopher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it's working for me.

```
UPDATE Team
SET GroupID = CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*10000000 AS INT)
WHERE GroupID IN (SELECT GroupID FROM Team
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING COUNT(GroupID)<4)
```

This code ensures random values are assigned for all GroupId's in Team table AND no GroupID would have an occurrence of more than 4

Comment: .. You should write the logic so it produces four values rather than 1000000 values.

Comment: @SandySands Yes this works, thanks. Any way to make it so that the same number can't appear more than 4 times?

Comment: @SandySands I just tried this, and it affects 0 rows.

Comment: I tested it again and it runs fine. Just copy the exact text as given above and try again for table Team and column GroupID

Comment: @SandySands (0 row(s) affected) when I'm running the exact same query as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

```
SELECT *, ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %4) + 1 randomNumber
FROM TEAM
```

Used in an update:

```
UPDATE Team
SET GroupID = ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %4) + 1 randomNumber
```

Solution taken from:

[SQL SERVER – Random Number Generator Script – SQL Query](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/29/sql-server-random-number-generator-script-sql-query/)

> Note: The distribution is pretty good however there are the occasional peaks.