# Is it possible to create many rows on a select statement without table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to know if it's possible to generate more than 1 row on this select statement:

```
select
      floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B1
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B2
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B3
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B4
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B5
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B6 ;
```

instead of this ( single row)

```
    B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
    -- --   --  --  --  --
    48  35  30  44  31  24
```

I would like to see this ( or many rows as I want like in a loop or while)

```
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
-- --   --  --  --  --
48  35  30  44  31  24
24  2   34  15  22  15
11  7   2   36  27  26
49  19  44  17  49  47
39  4   48  32  16  34
23  10  32  29  48  9
45  49  13  17  45  25
38  16  15  25  33  41
```

If anyone knows if is it possible to do that without creating procedures I would appreciate !

Comment: no. you'd have to change to multiple selects and `union`. e.g. `select 'a' union all select 'b' union all .... select 'z'`.

Comment: @MarcB Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: Can we use an existing database table in our answer?  In other words, can we query a built-in mysql table?

Comment: @MarcB you're thoughtful, I appreciate your suggestion it works.. why this haven't come to my mind before...

Thank you everyone for the time and appreciation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most databases provide a way to generate 1..n rows of data (see: [SQL SELECT to get the first N positive integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475973/sql-select-to-get-the-first-n-positive-integers)) but MySQL doesn't make it easy.  If you have a table that you know has enough rows to meet your requirements you can use that as a basis for a query to get what you want.

For example this will get you 10 rows:

```
SELECT @N := @N +1 AS rownumber
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B1
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B2
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B3
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B4
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B5
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B6 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, (SELECT @N:=0) dummyRowNums LIMIT 10;
```

You can use any table to achieve this as long as you can be sure it has more rows than the LIMIT you're looking to reach.

If you don't need a rownumber in your result set, you can remove the first column in the SELECT and can remove the join (", (SELECT @N:=0) dummyRowNums"):

```
SELECT floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B1
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B2
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B3
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B4
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B5
     ,floor(1+(rand()*(1+100-1))) as B6 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `(SELECT @N:=0)` here?

Comment: @AndriyM I updated the answer to clarify.  You only need that if you want to get a row number back in your results.  It's just a dummy value that is incremented.

Comment: Right, I just wasn't sure whether you forgot to include `@N+1` or you forgot to remove the subquery. I think the row numbering thing may be a useful addition, but at the same time I think it's redundant to your solution, as the OP never asked for it. It might even become more of a distraction for them (in fact, for anyone who is more or less still a newbie) in their attempt to understand how your answer works.

Comment: @AndriyM: fair enough.  I've updated the response with the exact query to be used if the row number is not needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, use a recursive CTE... and mind your seeds for the RAND function.

```
;With integers( num ) as
(
    Select 1 as num
        union all
    Select num + 1
        from integers
        where num <= 10
)
select
      num,
      floor(1+(rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(1+100-1))) as B1
     ,floor(1+(rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(1+100-1))) as B2
     ,floor(1+(rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(1+100-1))) as B3
     ,floor(1+(rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(1+100-1))) as B4
     ,floor(1+(rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(1+100-1))) as B5
     ,floor(1+(rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(1+100-1))) as B6 
    from integers
```

See this question for the RAND seed issue:
[RAND not different for every row in T-SQL UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214748/rand-not-different-for-every-row-in-t-sql-update)

Comment: The question isn't about SQL Server, though.

Comment: Yes, but someone will wander on here from Google 3 years from now and upvote my answer :) ...